# How do I move the Android SDK folder installed with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I've installed VS 2017 in its default path (C drive) but its used up most of my drive space due to the large Android folder at `C:\Users\USERNAME\Local\Android`. This folder was auto created by the VS 2017 installer. How do I move it to another drive and have VS detect it?

I've tried these solutions and they *don't work* with VS 2017.

- [How to make Visual Studio 2015 installer know that I already have Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792693/how-to-make-visual-studio-2015-installer-know-that-i-already-have-android-sdk#32658931)
- [Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Comment: The default folder Visual Studio installs Android SDK is now at: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the answer at last. Changing the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment var had no effect. The only way is moving the folder by hand, and then changing the Android SDK path setting under Options > Xamarin > Android Settings.

[image: settings]

Comment: I have just tried to do this, but I cannot change the Options setting above because when I click on the Xamarin node VS just hangs.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, fixed this by copying the Android folder rather than moving it, then changing the "Android SDK location" path.  After that I could delete the copy in "C:\Program Files(x86).

Answer (score 0):

Please be reminded you also need to change the Start Menu shortcut of SDK Manager and ADK Manager. It is especially important if you "copy" the SDK files to new location. Your old shortcuts are still valid and opening SDK Manager from Start Menu will haunt you with the old SDK path.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you be fine. I had the same problem.

After last update all, every was restored to write. Try include Android SDK using Visual Studio Installer.

And remember. VS must be opened as Administration always.

[image: Image of VS Installer for simple reference]

Comment: Don't forget to open VS on Administration mode.