# NativeScript ANDROID_HOME missing

Tags: android, macos, nativescript

When I run `tns run android` or `tns doctor` I get an error that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set.  Yet it's clearly set.  Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.3.

```
bash-3.2$ tns run android
The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
bash-3.2$ $ANDROID_HOME
bash: /Users/rlangton/Library/Android/sdk: is a directory
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Permissions is my first guess. I don't use a Mac often enough to know for certain but I've seen others report using sudo when setting up things works and others who don't need sudo. So maybe the cli doesn't have the perms to access :/

Comment: see here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1097  &  if u are using VS then see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792693/how-to-make-visual-studio-2015-installer-know-that-i-already-have-android-sdk

Comment: Try set your sdk location path that may be help you [android sdk locaiton path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using bash then you need to update the ~/.bash_profile file.
In my case, I'm using ZSH so I needed to edit ~/.zshrc file.

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add the export line below:

```
if [ -f /Users/{myusername}/.tnsrc ]; then
    source /Users/{myusername}/.tnsrc
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{myusername}/Library/Android/sdk
fi
```

Ctrl + O to save, Ctrl + X to exit.  Restart the terminal.  Now `echo $ANDROID_HOME` shows the correct path every time.

Answer (score 7):

Open/create `.profile` like this

`vim ~/.profile`

add the following lines to the end of the `.profile` file.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
```

load the profile using the command

```
source ~/.profile
```

You should have it working I guess. This is what I did to get this configured.

Comment: I am using windows and I am also getting some type of same error `The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.` Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: @ClimbTree please try editing the environmental variables and adding a variable `ANDROID_HOME ` with value as path to the `sdk` folder.