# Use existing Android SDK and virtual devices in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, ionic2, visual-studio-2017, apache-cordova

I wanted to test [Ionic  2 templates for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.Ionic2TemplatesforVisualStudio2017). I have previously installed Android SDK, HAXM and running emulator. I have ADT_HOME pointing to existing Android SDK but Visual Studio wants me to install Android SDK and emulator using Visual Studio 2017 installer. 
How can I force Visual Studio 2017 to notice and use existing installation?

Comment: did u try this..? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31792693/7012517

Comment: @Shobhit yes, no change